# Nomination owner highlight is displayer in the comments only after clicking the "show n more comments" link

Tags: bug, comments, design, election, nominations

When navigating to the [election nomination page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11?tab=nomination), in the comments section, by default there is no highlight for the nomination owner.

But when I click the "show n more comments" link at the end of the comments section, after all the comments are loaded, there is a highlight applied for the nomination user in their comments.

It seems `owner` CSS class is added after the click of "show n more comments" link, which caused the inconsistency.

GIF for the same

> [image: nomination gif]

Comment: Can you share this GIF software? What's its name?

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ LiceCap..